Supabase Swift decoding issues when using foreign key
When providing a .select modifier that points to a foreign table, values fail to decode. I'm wondering if this is an issue in the way I'm declaring my select query, something to do with postgres or a bug in Supabase.
From what I can see, it looks as though value is decoding the wrong JSON string. If I look at the actual network response, the account value is an object, however the decoder thinks it is a string (presumably the foreign key in postgres). On the left you can see the raw API response, and on the right you can see what Supabase is trying to decode.

To Reproduce
Models
struct Transaction: Codable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var subtitle: String?
    var merchant: String?
    var amount: Decimal
    var tax_deductible: Bool = false
    var date: Date
    var account: TransactionAccount?
}

enum AccountType: String, Codable, CaseIterable {
    case debit
    case savings
    case loan
    case credit
    case cash
}

struct TransactionAccount: Codable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var description: String?
    var type: AccountType
    var color: String
}

SDK Usage
do {
            return try await Database.shared
                .client
                .database
                .from("transactions")
                .select("*, account(*)")
                .in("type", value: scope.transactionTypes.map({ $0.rawValue }))
                .execute()
                .value
        } catch {
            return []
        }

Swift Error
Printing description of error:
▿ DecodingError
  ▿ typeMismatch : 2 elements
    - .0 : Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>
    ▿ .1 : Context
      ▿ codingPath : 2 elements
        ▿ 0 : _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2)
          ▿ rep : Rep
            - index : 2
        - 1 : CodingKeys(stringValue: "account", intValue: nil)
      - debugDescription : "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string instead."
      - underlyingError : nil

Expected behavior
The docs make it clear that I should be able to do this and get back the full object from the foreign table. https://supabase.com/docs/reference/swift/select?example=querying-foreign-table-with-count
Additional context
If I add every value to my query individually, the request works as expected:
do {
            return try await Database.shared
                .client
                .database
                .from("transactions")
                .select(
                """
            id,
            description,
            amount,
            type,
            date,
            name,
            tax_deductible,
            account(*)
            """
            )
                .in("type", value: scope.transactionTypes.map({ $0.rawValue }))
                .execute()
                .value
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }


this was answered on GH Issue (https://github.com/supabase/supabase-swift/issues/322).

The issue is quite clear in that it isn’t resolved…
